# Compare Two Character Arrays in C

Tags: c

I have a string struct.

```
struct string
{
   char *c;
   int length;
   int maxLength;
}
```

I want to check if two strings are equal.

So I want to run a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   if(s1[i] != s2[i]) // This code is more C# than C.
```

s1 and s2 are both string structs.

How do I do this `if(s1[i] != s2[i])` ?

**EDIT:**
I just did this, is it over kill?

```
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    if((*s1).c[i] != (*s2).c[i])
    {
        printf("Failed");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541094/string-comparison)

Comment: can we see the declaration of `s1` and `s2`

Comment: show how you declared s1 and s2

Comment: While you _can_ write `(*s1).c[i]`, a C programmer would write `s1->c[i]`.

Comment: What is the difference between (*s1) and s1->  ?

Comment: In C (not in C++) `(*s1).c` is the same as `s1->c` which is prefered for cosmetic reasons.

Comment: Thank you all; very insightful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to write the comparison code yourself, rather than using built-ins such as `strcmp()` — which might be performance boosted by being written in, or generated as, optimized assembler code.  The `are_equal()` function will return 1 (true) if the strings are equal and 0 (false) otherwise.

#### Sub-optimal solution

```
static inline int min(int a, int b) { return (a < b) ? a : b; }

int are_equal(const struct string *s1, const struct string *s2)
{
    int len = min(s1->length, s2->length);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s1->c[i] != s2->c[i])
            return 0;  // They are different
    }
    return(s1->c[i] == s2->c[i]);
}
```

The `inline` function assumes a C99 compiler; you can replace it with an appropriate macro if you're stuck using C89.

#### More nearly optimal solution

```
int are_equal(const struct string *s1, const struct string *s2)
{
    if (s1->length != s2->length)
        return 0; // They must be different
    for (int i = 0; i < s1->length; i++)
    {
        if (s1->c[i] != s2->c[i])
            return 0;  // They are different
    }
    return 1;  // They must be the same
}
```

Both versions of the code assume that the strings in `s1->c` and `s2->c` are null-terminated and that `s1->length == strlen(s1->c)` and `s2->length == strlen(s2->c)`.

With C99, it would also be possible to use `_Bool` as the return type, or `<stdbool.h>` and `bool` (as the return type) and `true` and `false` as the return values.

#### Alternative solution using `strcmp()`

Note that if you simply use `strcmp()`, you will get 0 if the strings are equal and a non-zero value if the strings are unequal.  So, you might also write the function like this to return true if the strings are equal and false otherwise:

```
int are_equal(const struct string *s1, const struct string *s2)
{
    return strcmp(s1->c, s2->c) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Why check for min? **min(s1->length, s2->length);** Shouldn't the size be the same if they are equal? That is, if their lengths are different that would yield a return false. I would compare their lengths before running the for loop -- just a suggestion.

Comment: @Redanium: thanks for the fix — I've incorporated the important part of it into the answer.  I'm sorry your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12050036) got rejected, though I probably would have undone the change of return type (you'd made it `bool`, which is not wrong, but not consistent with the rest of the post).

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you can use C-strings with `\0` termination I would do that and use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp):

```
if (strcmp(s1.c, s2.c)) {
    // action if strings are not equal
}
```

Comment: You should probably note here that you will do the stuff in the `if` statement if the strings ARE NOT equal.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement is incomplete (perhaps lacking setting a flag then a `break` or a `return`), and you don't use the `struct` so perhaps

```
struct string {
  char *c;
  int length;
  int maxLength;
};

bool same_string (struct string *s1, struct string* s2) {
  int ln1 = s1->length;
  if (ln1 != s2->length) return false;
  for (int i=0; i<ln1; i++)
    if (s1->c[i] != s2[ci]) return false;
  return true;
}
```

But you really want `strncmp` i.e. just

```
bool same_string (struct string *s1, struct string* s2) {
  if (s1->length != s2->length) return false;
  return strncmp(s1->c, s2->c, s1->length)==0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare each member

```
int compare(struct string s1, struct string s2){

return (strcmp(s1.c,s2.c) == 0) && 
       (s1.maxLength ==s2.maxLength) &&
       (s1.length ==s2.length) ;
}

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   if(!compare(s1,s2)) { 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to know the length of the strings to compare them. You can use the string compare tools in the standard library `strncmp` preferably over `strcmp`, or you can write your own similar to this:

```
int strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; s1[i] == s2[i]; i++)
    if (s1[i] == '\0')
      return 0;
  return s1[i] - s2[i];
}
```